# How to render a remote file with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sitemap

I have the sitemap of www.mysite.com hosted on https://s3.amazonaws.com/mysite/sitemaps/sitemap1.xml.gz

Is it possible to configure Rails (routes, controllers, ...) to render the file sitemap1.xml under www.mysite.com/sitemap1.xml.gz?

Thanks.

Ps. the reason why the sitemap is under AWS is this:
https://github.com/kjvarga/sitemap_generator/wiki/Generate-Sitemaps-on-read-only-filesystems-like-Heroku

Comment: Why not just define a route to a controller that downloads that file and serves it as output?

Comment: Surely it's trivial, but could you provide an example? Thanks.

Comment: looks like someone already wrote an example in their answer ;) A redirect would be simpler actually.

Comment: Hi all,
any news here? I have exactly the same problem and I can't find nothing around the web about this...

Comment: Did you find a solution? Sharing it here would be useful. (It is also ok to accept your own answer.)

Answer (score 3):

based on https://github.com/kjvarga/sitemap_generator/issues/173

I'm trying this...
in `routes.rb`

`get 'sitemap(:id).:format.:compression' => 'sitemap#show'`

in `sitemap_controller.rb`

```
class SitemapController < ApplicationController
  def show
    data = open("http://{ENV['AWS_BUCKET_PROD']}.s3.amazonaws.com/sitemaps/sitemap#{params[:id]}.xml.gz")
    send_data data.read, :type => data.content_type
  end
end
```

Also make sure that sitemap   (index) file contains links to other sitemap files (sitemap1, sitemap2...) located at your site and not amazon.

Comment: This is probably the only way. Excellent!

Comment: Can you kindly tell me that what is the reason behind this "Also make sure that sitemap (index) file contains links to other sitemap files (sitemap1, sitemap2...) located at your site and not amazon." ?

Comment: @Mohsin Sethi, it's been 5 years since I did it. So I don't know. You may not need it, or the reason you need it is the same as the reason you need to serve your index sitemap from your site and not from aws directly.

Answer (score 0):

Create a controller that would redirect to Amazon S3 file location and create a matching route for it.

routes.rb:

```
match 'sitemap1.xml.gz' => 'site_map#redirect'
```

site_map_controller.b:

```
class SiteMapController < ApplicationController
   def redirect
      redirect_to 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/mysite/sitemaps/sitemap1.xml.gz'
   end
end
```

Comment: Although the url is correct s3 needs credentials. So this won't work.

Comment: The problem is that Google is not happy if you serve a sitemap with a redirect, as the sitemap need to be served from within the mapped domain. Additionally, in this way you're exposing the s3 directory, which is not a best practice.

Comment: As Topo said a sitemap should not be after a redirect, this solution will not work

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you are deploying to a read-only filesystem such as Heroku.

If so, here are some articles that will help:

- [Creating a sitemap for Rails and Heroku](http://blog.dynamic50.com/2010/09/09/creating-a-sitemap-for-rails-and-heroku/): "To solve this, we wrote a quick controller action to create the sitemap on the fly, and then cached it using page caching."
- [Rails Google Sitemaps on Heroku](http://teabass.com/posts/rails-google-sitemaps-on-heroku): shows how to use a controller to parse the external sitemap and then render the sitemap XML.
- [Generating a sitemap.xml file on Heroku with Ruby on Rails](http://www.azgaard.com/2012/06/06/generating-a-sitemap-xml-file-on-heroku-with-ruby-on-rails/): "Here is a description of how to dynamically generate an xml sitemap every time it is accessed."